# How to Execute Query within Flag condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to execute an Excel dataset within an condition. The dataset keeps on getting updated on daily intervals, therefore i have created a 'Flag' column. Whwnever New data is being updated it is marked in Flag column as **'Not Feasible'**, when it is processed Flag column gets updated to **'Feasible'**. If an entry is marked as 'Not Feasible' means it has not been processed yet and we need to execute the script having Flag value as **'Not Feasible'**.

**What i need to perform :** I only want to execute the cleaning process under for loop(by processing one  row at a time) on entries with the **'Not Feasible'** Flag column values.

After Successful execution need to concat the executed data (df) + Non Executed Data(df1).

**Input Data**

```
name  Joining_Date      age   Contact    col4   col5  col6  flag

NKJ    4/26/2021        48!   96754789   8886H  AHBZ        Not feasible
Tom    26.4.2021        27    98468300   ^686H  ANKZ        feasible
Mike   2/27/2021        28@   78915359   3256H  AK9Z        Not feasible
NKJ    27.2.2021        48!   96754789   8886H  AHBZ        Not feasible
Adam   2/14/2021        18#   78915899   3256H  AK7Z        Not feasible
Steve  3/11/2021        23@   7891HI59   3256H  AK5Z        feasible
JKN    2/12/2021        35    96451188   3566H  NK4Z        Not feasible
```

Script using :

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')

df1 = df.loc[df['flag'] != 'Not feasible'] 
df = df.loc[df['flag'] == 'Not feasible'].copy()

for index, file in df..iterrows():
   # Run your cleaning codes with original syntax   
   try:
      file['Joining_Date'][index] = pd.to_datetime(file['Joining_Date'], errors='coerce')
      file['Joining_Date'][index] = file['Joining_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      file['age'][index] = file['age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
      file[['col4','col5']][index] = file[['col4','col5']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
      file['Contact'][index] = file['Contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
      file['flag'][index] = "feasible"
   except ValueError:
      file['status'] = ValueError

   df = pd.concat([file, df1]).sort_index() 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Error:df = pd.concat([file, df1]).sort_index()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

**Expected Output:**

```
name  Joining_Date      age   Contact    col4   col5  col6  flag

NKJ    2021-4-26        48    96754789   8886H  AHBZ        feasible
Tom    26.4.2021        27    98468300   ^686H  ANKZ        feasible
Mike   2021-2-27        28    78915359   3256H  AK9Z        feasible
NKJ    2021-2-27        48    96754789   8886H  AHBZ        feasible
Adam   2021-2-14        18    78915899   3256H  AK7Z        feasible
Steve  3/11/2021        23@   7891HI59   3256H  AK5Z        feasible
JKN    2021-2-12        35    96451188   3566H  NK4Z        feasible
```

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can completely remove looping and use:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['flag'] != 'Not feasible'] 
df = df.loc[df['flag'] == 'Not feasible'].copy()

df['Joining_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Joining_Date'], errors='coerce')
df['Joining_Date'] = df['Joining_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['age'] = df['age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
df[['col4','col5']] = df[['col4','col5']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W','', regex=True))
df['Contact'] = df['Contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
df['flag'] = "feasible"


df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index()
```

EDIT: Loop solution is possible, but for replace is used `re.sub`, because working with scalars:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['flag'] != 'Not feasible'] 
df = df.loc[df['flag'] == 'Not feasible'].copy()

import re
    
def test(x):
    
    try:
        x['Joining_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(x['Joining_Date'], errors='coerce')
        x['Joining_Date'] = x['Joining_Date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        x['age'] = float(re.sub('[^\d.]', '',x['age']))
        x['col4'] = re.sub('\W', '',str(x['col4']))
        x['col5'] = re.sub('\W', '', str(x['col5']))
        
        x['Contact'] = float(re.sub('[^\d.]', '',x['Contact']))
        x['flag'] = "feasible"
    except ValueError:
        x['status'] = ValueError

    return x


df = df.apply(test, axis=1)

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index()
```

Comment: Sir, There is an requirement, where i need to execute this under Loop only as i have to update the status column for each Try and except condition under for loop, Is there a way where i can use this under the for loop.

Comment: @NKJ - Possible, but need forget for many pandas functions, working with scalars

Comment: Sir, As using the suggested code , if there is any row values with incorrect format, the script gets aborted, But i am looking to execute the next line if there is any error in row values and appending the error in status column.

Comment: Sir , Please Suggest how it can be corrected using the for loop. So that i can update the rows in "Status" column with particual Error if there is any error comes up and move to the next row and so on till the last row in the dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, SIr but Using suggested code, If any of the row have the wrong data , it gets aborted , My reason of using for loop was to process each row at a time and if there is any wrong data column Status needs to be updated and skips to the next row.

Comment: @NKJ Hmm, for me working this way like need, for you not?